# Using awk in a makefile to read version numbers

Tags: regex, bash, awk, makefile, binaries

As the title says, I'm trying to use awk inside my makefile to pull a version number. Once the version number is pulled, it gets exported and tacked onto the end of the packages I create. I have the export part working. Problem is that any binaries I create are labelled 'foobin-2.bin' instead of 'foobin-2.0.0.0.67.bin'

I have a version file, called 'foo_version.mk'

Here are its contents:

```
#version.mk.
VERSION 2.0.0.0.67
```

Here's what my makefile does:

```
export version = $(shell awk '{ v[$$1] = $$2; } \
                 END {printf("%d.", \
                     v["VERSION"]); \
                   }' version.mk)
```

As you can probably tell, I'm new to awk and my experience has been limited to using and editing other peoples' stuff. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` is telling awk to convert the version to a decimal number and so dropping everything after the first `.`. You probably wanted `%s` but it's unnecessary to use `printf` at all and you also don't need an array. Assuming your makefile syntax requires every `$` to be doubled like in your current script, all you need is:

```
export version = $(shell awk '$$1=="VERSION"{ print $$2"." }' version.mk)
```